# login log, find time period between last log in and log out

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

i have a sql code to find out the user's last log in and log out, but the log IN and OUT are defined by special variable #in_out# anyway here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
                0 AS TIP,
                CP.PARTNER_ID P_ID,
                CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_NAME P_NAME,
                CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_SURNAME P_SURNAME,
                WL.PARTNER_ID W_ID,
                WL.DOMAIN_NAME DOMAIN,
                WL.IN_OUT_TIME IN_OUT_TIME,
                WL.IN_OUT IN_OUT,
                C.FULLNAME C_NAME
            FROM
                COMPANY_PARTNER CP
                LEFT OUTER JOIN WRK_LOGIN WL ON WL.PARTNER_ID = CP.PARTNER_ID 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY C ON C.COMPANY_ID=CP.COMPANY_ID
            WHERE
                <cfif isdate(attributes.start_date)>WL.IN_OUT_TIME >= #attributes.start_date# AND</cfif>
                <cfif isdate(attributes.finish_date)>WL.IN_OUT_TIME < #dateadd('d',1,attributes.finish_date)# AND</cfif>
                <cfif len(attributes.domain_name)>WL.DOMAIN_NAME = '#attributes.domain_name#' AND</cfif>
                <cfif len(attributes.in_out)>WL.IN_OUT = #attributes.in_out# AND</cfif>
                WL.DOMAIN_NAME IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY
                CP.PARTNER_ID,WL.PARTNER_ID,WL.IN_OUT_TIME,WL.IN_OUT,CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_NAME,CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_SURNAME,WL.DOMAIN_NAME,C.FULLNAME
```

and the table:

```
<cfoutput query="get_wrk_login" startrow="#attributes.startrow#" maxrows="#attributes.maxrows#" group="P_ID">
                    <cfif in_out eq 1><cfset date1 = '#in_out_time#'></cfif>
                    <cfif in_out eq 0><cfset date2 = '#in_out_time#'></cfif>
                    <cfif not isdefined('date2')><cfset online_time = 30><cfelse><cfset online_time = datediff("n", date1, date2)></cfif>
                <tr height="20" onMouseOver="this.className='color-light';" onMouseOut="this.className='color-row';" class="color-row">
                    <td width="100" align="center">#dateformat(in_out_time,'dd/mm/yyyy')# #timeformat(dateadd('h',2,in_out_time),'HH:MM')#</td>
                    <td>#p_name# #p_surname# #online_time#</td>
                    <td align="center"><cfif tip eq 0>Kurumsal<cfelse>Biriyesel</cfif></td>
                    <td width="130">#left(C_NAME,20)#</td>
                    <td width="100">#domain#</td>
                    <td align="center"><cfif in_out eq 1><cf_get_lang_main no='142.Giriş'><cfelse><cf_get_lang_main no='19.Çıkış'></cfif></td>
                </tr>
                </cfoutput>
```

the problem is that i cant set the date1 and date2 to a last log in and out, because the time is defined just once in a loop, and said to be IN or OUT log, if in the loop it was defined in the same time the LOG IN and LOG OUT time, i would have easily datediff em, but it defined once in a loop, i hope u understood me ^.^ but now im getting the result even minus minutes )) so it is deffinetly wrong, thus im asking for help, and thank you all for help!

Comment: Is WL.IN_OUT a BIT field? If it is then what does it represent?

Comment: Barry, It define whether it was login or logout, if in_out is 1 then all the data and the date are for Log IN, but if it is 0 then it means all the data is for LOG OUT

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. It would help to see a sample of the query data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said `WL.IN_OUT` is a BIT field, so can only ever be 1 or 0.

This means that only date1 OR date2 can be defined. They can not both be defined at the same time.

What you are saying in the code below is that if date2 is defined then get the difference between date1 and date2. If date2 is defined, date1 will never be defined, and vice versa.

```
<cfif in_out eq 1><cfset date1 = '#in_out_time#'></cfif>
<cfif in_out eq 0><cfset date2 = '#in_out_time#'></cfif>
<cfif not isdefined('date2')><cfset online_time = 30><cfelse><cfset online_time = datediff("n", date1, date2)></cfif>
```

From the query you provided above it is not possible to get the difference between the login and logout date, because you only have 1 date,  `WL.IN_OUT_TIME IN_OUT_TIME`, which is going  to be either the login, or logout date.

Comment: so u say there is no answer to this question? i mean it is impossible to count the difference between log in and out?!

Comment: As far as I can see, using the query you have provided, it is not possible. Do you store both the login and logout date in separate fields? From the query it looks like you only have 1 date, which represents either the last login or logout date.

Comment: but as for the other loop, the logout inf. goes right after the login inf, actually there is the inf about the log in and out, just the loops are different

Comment: Are you saying that there is another loop and/or query for logout? Can you post more information?

Comment: i mean are there any way define for example if the id of the login is the same as for the id of the logout, then set the dates?!

Comment: there is no other query, thats all i have

Comment: Is there a 1 to 1 relationship between WRK_LOGIN and COMPANY_PARTNER  on PARTNER_ID, or is a record entered in WRK_LOGIN every time a partner logs in or logs out?

Comment: what does it mean 1to1 relation? ) actually, by this id they are connected, defined

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4417/discussion-between-user775917-and-barry-jordan)